# Updating frame buffer

Tags: c++, openscenegraph

I am creating two windows in osg using osg::GraphicsContext and each window is separted into 4 parts where I render different images. I want to create transformation on one model in one image, so one out of four models in one window will have some kind of transformation. Below is the code that I am using.

The problem is if I have transformation on just one model does osg knows that it needs to update only that one frame buffer or does it update everything from the beginning even the ones that have no changes by frame?

```
osg::ref_ptrosgViewer::Viewer view1 = new osgViewer::Viewer;
osg::ref_ptrosgViewer::Viewer view2 = new osgViewer::Viewer;
// rest of the code...

// prepare viewer for rendering
view1->realize();
view2->realize();

while (!view1->done() && !view2->done()) 
{
    // Update transformations on models on images
    osg::Matrix matrix = transform->getMatrix();
    matrix *= osg::Matrix::rotate(osg::Quat(osg::inDegrees(1.0), osg::Vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)));
    transform->setMatrix(matrix);

    view1->frame();
    view2->frame();
}
```

Comment: In 2d raster graphics, it was usual to update only invalidated regions, i.e. as least as possible (due to limited resources when these were state of the art). With OpenGL and other 3d APIs, it became usual to re-render everything. Considering that parts of 3d geometry may overlap (view dependent), which can be resolved at pixel or sub-pixel level, it's hard to imagine how else it could be done. Of course, a "snapshot" could be done after rendering to re-render only views which are affected by changes while others just repaint the snapshot but I'm not aware whether this is used anywhere.

Comment: This could be done in custom code (with more or less significant additional effort). Considering this additional effort and the power of current graphics H/W, it's probably rarely done.

Comment: Additionally, modern GPUs usually work concurrently to the CPU. That forces a kind of pipeline where on CPU side rendering is initiated but finally done on GPU while the CPU is already doing something else. To make a snapshot would mean to wait (or check periodically) on CPU side when GPU is done. This may result in stalling the CPU which is usually not intended.